# Python phone number string validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation

I'm having some issues that I really would like some help on. Right now I'm trying to get the user to input a phone that only accepts the first three things typed in as numbers. The rest can be letters that will get converted into numbers, but even if the first three things are numbers or letters it will keep repeating. The input has to be in this format (XXX-XXX-XXXX). 
examples: (234-SDF-SDFL) this would pass, if (SDF-FSD-UEIE) then the program would ask again until the first three are number. Please and thank you.

```
phNumber=input("Number: ")
num=phNumber.split("-")
area=num[0]

while area.isdigit() == False :
    phNumber=input("Number: ")
    num=phNumber.split("-")
    area=num[0]
```

Comment: What is the issue? For example, is the problem that the program as you wrote it will accept "111-A" even though it shouldn't? Do you want a solution that keeps the spirit of what you wrote or do you just want to parse a phone number in any way convenient? Are you open to using a library like https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/ (note I have never used it personally)?

Comment: So it's stuck in an infinite loop constantly asking for Number, I want it to only accept the three things as numbers. Anything else the program will keep asking the user until it is only numbers. Once someone puts in a phone number like (348-YES-SDKJ) it will then convert all the letters into numbers like (348-937-7355) and I'm open to anything that works

Comment: Your program will exit the loop if you type in three numbers followed by a "-".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use regular expressions? (BTW: Do not use this odd naming, use pythons naming convention: snake case)

import re

```
phone_number=input("Number: ")

while not re.match(r'^\d{3}-[A-Z]{3}-[A-Z]{4}$', phone_number):
    phone_number=input("Number: ")
```

Comment: Thank you, I have no idea what regular expressions are. I'm new to programming, and I will have to study what these are. Thank you again.